# Estimating Server Resources

Tags: wordpress, webserver, resources

I am planning on building a Wordpress multisite with a business and revenue model based on edublogs.com and Wordpress.com.

As I am selecting the test and the production environment, how would I go about estimating server resources for the multisite? I am leaning towards using AWS as a dedicated host and server resources can expanded based on usage needs....

...but I am looking to draft a CPU and bandwidth estimate to send to my team for review. As far as CPU is concerned, how would I estimate server resources based on each individual site having the the following features:

Woocommerce, Appointment Booking Plugin, Visual Composer, Domain Mapping, Mail Fowarding.

Is there any way I can go about doing this? Also, can I use a premium theme like X or Divi for the planned multisite?

Thank you much

Comment: It is almost impossible for us to say. I used to do this for a living and here is what I did. I built reasonable a model, created a fairly sizable real-person pool and pounded the server. From there I measured metrics mostly about how many requests a pool of xx users can generate and what type of requests are made. From there, I used another machine with testing software to mimic the user behavior I saw using real-world scenarios. Then I payed attention to metrics and extrapolated using a curve (upward) to say if 100 used x resources then 1000 users would use ... ? After so many tests, it was

Comment: a matter of extracting similar circumstances and guesstimating. If this is too much, then just go for the gold. Most servers are fast enough assuming you do not cheap out. Get decent CPUs, a fair amount of memory, and always decent drives in a raid. Keep in mind that while CPU is all the rage, memory and disk are your friends. Also know that the more memory you have the more swap you do. The exception is for some application caches such as MySQL which are allocated differently. Otherwise, the more you put into memory, the more you need your swap space which means I/O.